# How to remove number and percentage from tooltip in google chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am trying to change tooltip value in google chart. I want to show only text field inside tooltip in my chart. But when I mouse hover on my chart it shows number and percentage. More clearly, (From image) I want to show only "Sleep" not the "7(29.2%)".Please share with me if any one have any idea.

My Jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/1c3atn9z/1/

My codes are below:

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No standard way to do it, you can only choose slice text. You could do a workaround this way though:

```
var options = {
  title: 'My Daily Activities',
  is3D: true,
  tooltip: { isHtml: true }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(hover){
        if(hover){
            $('.google-visualization-tooltip-item:eq(1)').remove() // remove the other info
        }
    })

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Be sure to add the `tooltip: { isHtml: true }` for it to work

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/1c3atn9z/2/

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle. Its not working for me. Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/1c3atn9z/1/

Comment: @PriyankDey added fiddle, you were probably missing jquery library ;)